# Change z-Index on <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an effect where, in the moment you click an icon, his background (width and height) is increase to 100% of the page. But what I'm not able to do is that the 'effect' goes under the `this.element` and over the rest.
I tried changing the position and zIndex, but I guess playing with a list is a bit different..
I let the code and the demo.

**Html**

```
     <ul>
        <li style="z-index:1;">
            <img src=".png" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#11D1AC;">
        </li>
        <li style="z-index:1;">
            <img src=".png" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#787FA7;">
        </li>
        <li style="z-index:1;">
            <img src=".png" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#FF7059;">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Js**

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
            var elementoPos = $(this).find('img').position();
            $(this).parent().css("zIndex", 3);
            var elementColor = $(this).find('img').css('backgroundColor');


            var square = document.createElement('div');
            $(square).css({
                "position": "absolute"
                , "zIndex": "2"
                , "width": "50"
                , "height": "50"
                , "left": elementoPos.left + 50 / 2
                , "top": elementoPos.top + 50 / 2
                , "backgroundColor": elementColor
            });
            $('body').append($(square));

            $(square).animate({
                "width": "100vw"
                , "height": "100vh"
                , "left": "0"
                , "top": "0"
            }, function () {
                $(square).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 1500);
            });
            //$('ul').slideUp('slow');

        });
```

Here is the demo:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/w4f3aj1z/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$(this).parent().css("zIndex", 3);` to this: `$(this).css({"z-index": 3,"position":"relative"});`  - if I understood correctly what you want

Comment: That's is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically created div was making problem.

So try `$(square).remove();` in animation end.

```
$(document).on('click','li', function () {
            var elementoPos = $(this).find('img').position();
            $(this).parent().css("zIndex", 3);
            var elementColor = $(this).find('img').css('backgroundColor');


            var square = document.createElement('div');
            $(square).css({
                "position": "absolute"
                , "zIndex": "2"
                , "width": "50"
                , "height": "50"
                , "left": elementoPos.left + 50 / 2
                , "top": elementoPos.top + 50 / 2
                , "backgroundColor": elementColor
            });
            $('body').append($(square));

            $(square).animate({
                "width": "100vw"
                , "height": "100vh"
                , "left": "0"
                , "top": "0"
            }, function () {
                $(square).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 1500, function() { $(square).remove(); });

            });
            //$('ul').slideUp('slow');

        });
```

Comment: added $(square).remove(); in square animation in last.

Comment: That only remove the square div. What I'm trying to do, is that the square goes OVER the rest of <li> and UNDER the <li> you clicked.

Comment: ok, sorry. I'll try o be more specific. When you clicked a li, there is a effect where you see how its width and height goes expand (although that is just the square we created). So I need that the square visually be in a lower layer(z-index), goes under, than the <li> you has clicked.

Comment: or simply `$(square).fadeOut(1500);`